# Swagger-like to Nestjs Microservices

Tags: microservices, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

Is there any swagger-like to nestjs microservices?

The [@nestjs/swagger](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger) lib only accepts normal nestjs applications, not microservices.

Answer (score 3):

[OpenAPI (aka Swagger)](https://www.openapis.org/) is specifically made for REST applications. If you're looking for documenting your Microservices, you can use something like [Async API](https://www.asyncapi.com/). There's a [community package](https://github.com/underfisk/nestjs-asyncapi) for NestJS as well that's currently in the works. You can watch the project for updates.